# What is a FILE in C?

Tags: c

In C programming what is a `FILE`?
A datatype, preprocessor directive or a datatype?

I run a simple program considering it as a datatype to find its size.
In an online compiler I got **216 bytes** and in turbo C I got **16 bytes** which makes it like a `long double` datatype.

Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/FILE "C standard does not specify whether FILE is a complete object type." (It's up to compiler implementation.) Simple 2 second Google search.

Answer (score 2):

The C Standard defines `FILE` this way:

> **7.23 Input/output <stdio.h>**
> **7.23.1 Introduction**
> 1  The header `<stdio.h>` defines several macros, and declares three types and many functions for performing input and output.
> [...]
> The types declared are `size_t` (described in 7.21);
>
> ```
>   FILE
> ```
>
> which is an object type capable of recording all the information needed to control a stream, including its file position indicator, a pointer to its associated buffer (if any), an error indicator that records whether a read/write error has occurred, and an end-of-file indicator that records whether the end of the file has been reached; [...]

So `FILE` is defined as a type in `<stdio.h>`. This type may be a complete type fully defined in the header file or left as an incomplete type, such as by `typedef struct FILE FILE;`.  So its size may not even be available via `sizeof(FILE)` and in any case, it is implementation defined and nothing can be inferred regarding its implementation from the value of `sizeof(FILE)`.  `FILE` could be a scalar type such as an integer type, a pointer type, a structure, a union... It does not matter for user programs that only manipulate `FILE *` objects, either the default streams `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` or those returned by standard library functions `fopen()`, `freopen()`, `tmpfile()` etc.

If you are interested in the implementation details, look for open source C libraries available on the Internet, preferably a simpler one such as the [newlib](https://sourceware.org/newlib/) or the [musl](https://musl.libc.org/) C libraries.